# userdata validation failed: typeofatrocity: Cast to Array failed for value "[object Object]" at path "typeofatrocity"

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, react-select

I am new to mongoose and MongoDB and I am trying to send data from my front end to the server and save it. But if I use my userdata Model as

```
typeofatrocity:{
   type: String 
}
```

The data is being stored as

```
"typeofatrocity": [
    "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" 
],
```

The console log of data I am sending  [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J04Eb.jpg)
This data was generated using react-select when I am selecting multiple options.
But if I change the userdata model to

```
var TypeofAtrocity = new mongoose.Schema([{
  value: String,
  label: String
}]);
typeofatrocity: {
  type: [TypeofAtrocity]
}
```

I get the error that

```
"userdata validation failed: typeofatrocity: Cast to Array failed for value "[object Object]" at path "typeofatrocity"
```

I am sending this data as formdata using `fromdata.append('typeofatrocity', typeofatrocity)`
then passing the formdata to the backend using axios and this formdata.

Comment: Do you want to save an array of object in typeofatrocity?

Comment: For ex. :  typeofatrocity: [{"value": "a", "label": "A"},{"value": "b", "label": "B"}]

Comment: please post your DB query in question.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the response, Actually I was sending the data as an Object so the data was being stored as "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"  , So while sending it to the server I changed it to JSON.stringify(datatosend) and then it was saving it properly, when I recieved the data back I used JSON.parse(datareturned) to convert it to Object.